# How to check if the function is called from foreign js file

Tags: javascript, function

There's a foreign JS file which is not loaded from our server on my page. In short I dont have any control on that file and I can't edit the file. I have created 1 function which I wish to call after the function which is in that foreign file is called.

I know the name of function of foreign file. I wish to call my function once the function from foreign file is executed. How can I do it?

Let me know if you dont understand my problem here. I'll try and explain it again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In short, you can't. If the foreign function sets some globally-accessible var or property, you could do an interval in your script to check for that, then call your function. But this is hacky. The situation is far from ideal.

Comment: where does jQuery come into play here?

Comment: @Alnitak Alright I removed jquery tag. Though i was using jquery to do my stuff. But I agree this is not a jquery related problem. Thanks.

Comment: @KuldeepDaftary my concern was that if the function in question was actually a jQuery plugin then the method to override it might be somewhat different.

Comment: ohh I see.. Well no its not a jquery plugin. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the foreign function is in the global scope you can replace it with your own wrapper:

```
var _old = foreignFunction;
foreignFunction = function() {

    // put pre-call stuff here
    ...

    // call with the original context and args
    _old.apply(this, arguments);  

    // and post-call stuff here
    ...
}
```

Note the use of `.apply` to ensure that whatever context and arguments were supplied to the original function are still supplied to it.  Without that, the `this` variable inside that function may not be what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Nice touch with .apply and the arguments variable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace the foreign function with your own. This may or may not be possible, depending on the order in which things are executed.

After the function (ForeignFunc()) is loaded onto the page

```
var _originalForeignFunc = ForeignFunc;
ForeignFunc = function() {
    _originalForeignFunc();
    //now do whatever you want to do here
    alert("After Foreign Func Execution");
}
```

Just remember, this will only work if you can replace `ForeignFunc()` with your own definition before it's actually called.